# correlation analysis with collapsed subjects

Tags: regression, correlation, stacking

I conducted an experiment with 21 subjects. Each subjects performed 80 trials for 3 different categories of test (total 240 trials). What I need to do now is look for a correlation between category 1/2/3 for each of the 80 trials and I need to do that by collapsing all subjects data as if they were produced by one single subject.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Also I  have a categorical dependent variable for each of the 80 trials, how can I do a regression which again collapsed all the subjects into one and uses category 1/2/3 as independent variables? Finally, in that case do I need to use a regressor which take into account the fact that data where produced by 21 different individuals?